# Ubuntu only using CPU not GPU when running games

Tags: wine, games, hardware, amd-graphics

Today I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and installed `amd radeon rx 550` driver (didn't showed any error while installing driver). I downloaded Counter Strike 1.6 and i noticed that it runs so slowly. When i checked everything was fine (fps wasn't limited), but fps was fine in lobby **100** fps, but in game when i'm moving left right it drops on **20-30** fps. When i played last month on Windows 7 it runs in **100** fps without problems. While playing game i saw on `htop` cpu cores are used above 60%. I think that ubuntu not using my gpu on games. How to active that?

Comment: Is this a laptop with hybrid graphics or do you actually have a dedicated GPU?